# Download file from ftp server

Tags: java, android, webserver

i am writing a small android application which requires some data which is stored on my web server. The file is a .txt file curretly less than 1 MB. Is it advisable to set up a ftp server to get the data or can i just use a http get method to get the contents on a file. If i am using a http get can someone please tell me the java code required for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is out of my head (so an error could have sneaked in):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.yourserver.com/some/path");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

try { 
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileutputStream("/path/to/your/output/file"); 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
    int len;
    while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: To avoid having your application marked as "not responding", make sure to do the download in a separate thread. See the Android page on AsyncTask, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.